# Android: Unable to find children in custom RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've extended the RelativeLayout class, and implemented all of the constructors as I think I need to. I've also added a child in the xml layout, just as I would with a regular RelativeLayout. Now, the problem is, I can't seem to access the children in the custom layout! Oddly, I can (in the graphical layout) select the child view and the custom layout is described as a 'parent', but no dice when trying to do it the other way around.

How do I 'tell' the class that it actually has children? Code below!

Thanks!

```java
private void init(Context context) {
    System.out.println(this.getChildCount()); // Always returns 0
}

public CustRLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CustRLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public CustRLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}
```

And the XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <app.hobi.CustRLayout android:id="@+id/cust"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/childView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img"
            android:src="@drawable/an_image" />
    </app.hobi.CustRLayout>

    <app.hobi.SomeOtherView android:id="@+id/other"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When you are in the `init()` method, your view is not yet completely created, not to mention it has not been through the layout-phase, so it won't have any children yet. You will have to wait until `onLayout` or even later to calculate how many children it has.

Comment: Ooh okay, I'll have a look. I'll report results! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The children get added later (after call to constructor) via `addChild()`. So  query the childCount at a late state e.g.: in onMeasure() or use the [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)

Comment: This is it - Jave mentioned it too, it works fine now! Thanks :D